# Attach event with Throw Expression

Tags: c#

I'm easing into C# 7 but my first Throw Expression doesn't compile.  What's wrong with this?

```
view.SelectionChanged +=
    something == true
        ? OnSelectionChanged
        : throw new InvalidOperationException();
```

The compiler errors is:

> Type of conditional expression cannot be determined because there is no implicit conversion between 'method group' and ''

Comment: That's not a lambda.

Comment: Have you set project's compilation to compile with c# 7?

Comment: @S.Petrosov Don't know what you mean. I'm using VS 2017.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will not work because the signature of the method group is not specified. `OnAction` is used as a method group. The type of `OnAction` is "method group" and there could potentially be multiple overloads of `OnAction` so the compiler cannot deduce it:

```
public void M() 
{
    var item = Console.Read();
    Func<object, object> ok = OnAction; // will work
    Func<object, object> handler = 
        item == 1 ? OnAction : throw new Exception(); // will not work
}

public static Object OnAction(object y)
{
    return "";
}
```

To fix it, all we need to do is specify the signature of the method group so the compiler knows exactly which one:

```
Func<object, object> handler = 
    item == 1 ? (Func<object, object>)OnAction : throw new Exception();
```

So to fix your issue, I am not sure what `SelectionChanged` is but you need to provide its signature and that will fix the issue.

Please note this error is not specific to C# 7.0. Even lower versions without *throw expressions* will also produce the same error.

[<== Fiddle Me ==>](https://dotnetfiddle.net/hkZGOp)

Answer (score 0):

Replace `throw new InvalidOperationException()` with

```
(sender,args)=>{throw new InvalidOperationException()}
```

Or Turn on building with c# 7 in this way:
Go to **Project Properties**->**Build**->**Advanced** -> **Language Version** set to c# 7.0 
[image]

Comment: That changes the meaning of the code to incorrect behavior.

Comment: The project is already set to `default` which in VS 2017 is C# 7.

Comment: @HappyNomad as I know the default is not C# 7

Comment: Well that's weird because I'm using other C# 7 features in the same project.